# OneToOne relationship doesn't always fetch

Tags: java, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I have a OneToOne relationship between two tables, as shown below:

PreRecordLoad.java:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="preRecordLoadId",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private PreRecordLoadAux preRecordLoadAux;
```

PreRecordLoadAux.java:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PRE_RECORD_LOAD_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRE_RECORD_LOAD_ID")
@OneToOne
private PreRecordLoad preRecordLoadId;
```

I'm using this method to pull back the PreRecordLoad object:

```
public PreRecordLoad FindPreRecordLoad(Long ID)
{
    print("Finding " + ID + "f");

    Query query;
    PreRecordLoad result = null;
    try
    {
        query = em.createNamedQuery("PreRecordLoad.findByPreRecordLoadId");
        query.setParameter("preRecordLoadId", ID);
        result = (PreRecordLoad)query.getSingleResult();
        //result = em.find(PreRecordLoad.class, ID);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        print(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
```

The '+ "f"' is to see if the passed value somehow had something at the end. It didn't.

I originally used em.find, but the same issue occurred no matter which method I used.

I used to use a BigDecimal for the ID because it was the default, and noticed I was getting a precision difference when it worked, and when it didn't work. Specifically the precision was 4 when it didn't work, but 0 when it did. I couldn't work out why this was, so I changed the BigDecimal to a Long, as I never really needed it to be a BigDecimal anyway.

When I save the new PreRecordLoad and PreRecordLoadAux objects to the database (inserting them for the first time), and then try and run this method to recall the objects, it retrieves the PreRecordLoad, but the PreRecordLoadAux is null. This is despite the entry being in the database and what looks to be full committed, as I can access it from SQLDeveloper, which is a separate session.

However, if I stop and re-run the application, then it successfully pulls back both objects. The ID being passed is the same both times, or at least appears to be.

Anyway suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thankyou.

Edit:

Here is the code for when I am persisting the objects into the DB:

```
    if(existingPreAux==null) {
        try {
            preLoad.setAuditSubLoadId(auditLoad);
            em.persist(preLoad);
            print("Pre Record Load entry Created");

            preAux.setPreRecordLoadId(preLoad);
            em.persist(preAux);
            print("Pre Record Load Aux entry Created");
        }
        catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
            for(ConstraintViolation c : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
                System.out.println (c.getPropertyPath() + " " + c.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            preLoad.setPreRecordLoadId(existingPreLoad.getPreRecordLoadId());
            preLoad.setAuditSubLoadId(auditLoad);
            em.merge(preLoad);
            print("Pre Record Load entry found and updated");

            preAux.setPreRecordLoadAuxId(existingPreAux.getPreRecordLoadAuxId());
            preAux.setPreRecordLoadId(preLoad);
            em.merge(preAux);
            print("Pre Record Load Aux entry found and updated");
        }
        catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
            for(ConstraintViolation c : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
                System.out.println (c.getPropertyPath() + " " + c.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

That's in a method, and after that code, the method ends.

Comment: I didn't read more thatn the first 2 lines, but I can say that the mapping is wrong alreay. If you have a OneToOne on one side, you must have a OneToOne on the other side. If you have a ManyToOne on one side, you must have a OneToMany on the other side. Also, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @JB Nizet Oh God, what an idiot. However did I not notice I had a ManyToOne and a OneToOne *facepalm*. Thanks, I'll change it. I still get the same error though I'm afraid. I shall update the question code.

Comment: Show us more of your code. My guess is that you're persisting and loading the objects in the same transaction, and neglect to initialize both sides of the association. If you haven't initialized both sides, you'll get your incorrect object from the first level cache.

Comment: @JB Nizet Ah, that sounds correct (not that I know about cache in depth, but that would give the observed issue). I've added some code, although the whole system is rather large so adding every piece would be a difficult task. Is there somewhere I can read about 'Initialization'? Thanks

Comment: It's your responsibility to maintain the coherence of the object graph. So, when you do `preAux.setPreRecordLoadId(preLoad);`, yo must also do `preLoad.setPreRecordLoadAux(preAux);`.

Comment: @JB Nizet Brilliant, that solved the issue. I'll keep note of that in future. Thank-you for the quick and great answers. If you'd like to summarize it in an answer, I'll accept and up-vote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your responsibility to maintain the coherence of the object graph. So, when you do `preAux.setPreRecordLoadId(preLoad);`, yo must also do `preLoad.setPreRecordLoadAux(preAux);`.

If you don't, then every time you'll load the `preAux` from the same session, it will be retrieved from the first-level cache, and will thus return your incorrectly initialized instance of the entity.